# Rich cards are not displayed when using multiple scripts

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

Is it possible to use multiple `script` elements without losing rich cards add-ons (rating value with the starts)?

I use two separate scripts - one for the `Product` type (where `AggregateRating` is used) and one for `Action` type. Even if I merge those two scripts into one, in search results there is no rating displayed.

The problem started when I replaced data generated by Yoast with my own script and change the `AggregateRating` type from Microdata to JSON-LD format. Then every rich card I had, disappeared. Since I've mentioned Yoast - this plugin generated the 3rd script on every page (`Website` type).

To sum up: previously I had one script with `Website` type generated by Yoast attached to every page, one with `AggregateRating` in Microdata on the product page, and one JSON-LD script with `Action` type (for `potentialAction` 's in Navbar, SideNav and Footer). Then I've replaced Yoast script with my own JSON-LD script (I've changed `Website` into `Organization`), changed Microdata to JSON-LD for `AggregateRating` in the product page. The last script for `Action` stayed the same.

Comment: Google’s Review snippets don’t make use of `Action`, or do they?

Comment: No, they don't. So if I attach more than one type (Action + Product) on the page, then nothing will be displayed? I thought that, if `Action` does not affect rich cards anyhow, then it won't be a problem, and `AggregateRating` will be shown in the snippet as usual.

Comment: It should be fine to provide more structured data than what Google uses for certain search features, of course. Whether or not you have `Action`, it shouldn’t affect getting the rich result. -- Did you really test it with actual search results, or are you talking about the Structured Data Testing Tool and its preview?

Comment: I've tested it on production. Structured Data Testing Tool - as you mentioned once - sometimes doesn't show Rich Cards in the preview, although they are displayed in search results properly. I've reduced the number of scripts and types to one per page and now it is displayed properly. However, it's only a temporary fix.